# Passing AActor reference into the nested object

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I want to do some logic of AActor in nested object and i need to pass this actor by reference to make it work. Unfortunatelly, i don't see a way how to pass "this" when "&" is used. Can someone explain me  what's going on?

```
ATestActor.h

class UHelper;
UCLASS()
class PROJECT_API ATestActor : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
    
public: 
    ATestActor();

protected:
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

public: 
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;

    UPROPERTY()
    UHelper* Helper;
};

UCLASS()
class PROJECT_API UHelper : public UObject
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    void Help(ATestActor* &TestActor)
    {
        // Do some stuff with testActor
    }
};

ATestActor.cpp

//other stuff

void ATestActor::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();
    Helper = NewObject<UHelper>();
    
    //How can i pass "this" to the method?
    //Helper->Help(&this);//incorrect
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&this` creates a pointer to a pointer. your function `Help` accepts a reference to a pointer. calling `Helper->Help(this);` should work since `this` is already a pointer, then we pass the ptr by reference when calling `Help`.

edit:

actually i forgot `this` is a [prvalue expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this) and prvalues cant bind to non const lvalue references.

you could do the following to get an lvalue of the `this` ptr.

```
auto* obj = this;
Helper->Help(obj);
```

Comment: I also though it should work this way, but in this case i get following:
"Non-const lvalue reference to type 'ATestActor*' cannot bind to rvalue of type 'ATestActor*'"

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: This answer is helpful because it explains what's going wrong, but the OP should consider why he's passing a pointer by reference - unless you're meaning to change the pointer, passing it simply as pointer should be preferable. (you can still 'do some stuff with testActor')

Comment: @BasinhetVeld I agree. I wasnt sure if it was okay to bring that up in the answer.